# Sorting in xslt does not work

Tags: sorting, xslt

I am trying to sort the xml based on the field value `person_id_external`.

The code which I am using is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="A/B">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
           <xsl:sort select="C/person_id_external" order="ascending" />        
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The payload is:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <logon_user_name>10027</logon_user_name>
            <person_id>1100111</person_id>
            <person_id_external>10027</person_id_external>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <logon_user_name>428122</logon_user_name>
            <person_id>11141</person_id>
            <person_id_external>111358</person_id_external>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <logon_user_name>428122</logon_user_name>
            <person_id>100441</person_id>
            <person_id_external>10636</person_id_external>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

The result provides a copy of the input but does not sort.

Expected result is :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <logon_user_name>10027</logon_user_name>
            <person_id>1100111</person_id>
            <person_id_external>10027</person_id_external>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <logon_user_name>428122</logon_user_name>
            <person_id>11141</person_id>
            <person_id_external>10636</person_id_external>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>
            <logon_user_name>428122</logon_user_name>
            <person_id>100441</person_id>
            <person_id_external>111358</person_id_external>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Cheers,
Vikcy

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example with more than one item to sort. -- **Hint:** XML is case-sensitive: `Person` does not match `<person>`.

Comment: Hi Michael, the person filed name with P caps was a typo. on changing that also the result is not sorted. regarding the payload the root CompoundEmployee will appear multiple times and will have only one person node unders which the person_id_external filed is present

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: first time user. Dont know how to edit the post :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***-- edited in response to your edit --***

In your example, each `B` node has only one `C` node. Therefore, you must sort the `B` nodes in order to get the expected result - and you must do so from the context of their parent `A`:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="C/person_id_external" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the default sort data-type is `text` (i.e. alphabetical).

Comment: @Vicky Adding the data type only changes the way nodes are sorted. Your question was why the nodes are not sorted at all.

Comment: yes the sorting wasnt working... it worked post adding the data type

Answer (score 0):

The below code works:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="C/person_id_external" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
```

The incoming payload had the type as number.

Cheers,
Vikas Singh